# PHP How to make 2 classes access methods from each one

Tags: php, oop

I have a simple php code and I want to split it into model,view,helper. Model should access some methods from helper class and helper class should access some methods from model class.

I am not sure if the below pattern is correct. I guess it is not because in this example model,view,helper will be initialized multiple times. Which is the most simple way to accomplish something like I am trying to do with the below code?

lib/main.php

```
require_once('lib/model.php');
require_once('lib/helper.php');
require_once('lib/view.php');

$action = isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : 'show'; 
switch($action){
  case "show": 
    $class->showAction();
    break;
  case "another":
    $class->anotherAction();
    break;
}
class main extends abstract{
  public function showAction(){
    if($this->helper->getParam('browse')){
      //something
    }else{
      $profiles= $this->model->getProfiles();
    }    
    echo $this->view->toHtml($profiles);  
  }
}
```

lib/abstract.php

```
class abstract{
  public function __construct(){    
    $this->model = new model();
    $this->view = new view();
    $this->helper = new helper();    
  }
}
```

lib/model.php

```
class model extends abstract{
  public function getProfiles(){
    if($this->helper->someMethod(){
      //some code
    }
    //some code
    return $profiles;
  }
}
```

lib/helper.php

```
class helper extends abstract{
  public function someHelperMethod(){
    if($this->model->someAnotherMethod(){
      //some code
    }
    //some code
    return $profiles;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a little tip that may be unrelated to the question. In PHP, `abstract` is a reserved word so you cannot use it as a class name.

Comment: More related to your question, If you're using newer versions of PHP. You can use a `trait`. A `trait` is a way of sharing methods to use on multiple classes.

Comment: @Jamesking56 The code will be used on different sites with different PHP versions.

Comment: You've done a great job getting your code down to a short readable example, but it'd probably be easier to answer if you expanded a bit on what Helper does (what is it helping to accomplish), because that would affect how one would recommend structuring it. Does it just store/get profiles?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. You could write one set of code and then use a VCS such as Git to keep your code in sync on each of the sites you deploy to.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for not using an MVC PHP framework such as Laravel, Codeigniter or Symfony? They already have setups like yours built-in that you can use. MVC stands for Model, View and Controller.

Comment: @Jamesking56 because I need to minimize as much as possible. It will be used for ajax call on each page and the code is less than 3000 lines all together.

Comment: Then why does it need to have a certain pattern? Patterns are best for larger code bases. What you need is simple code that is synced between the servers, your solution would be more of a server syncing tool than a programming tool / pattern.

Comment: @ahoffner honestly I don't have right now any example, I was just thinking if in the future there will be any requirements to call model within helper class. Right now there are just a few methods inside helper class such as getIsCrawler, getParam and none of them needs model.

Comment: You should seperate your classes more. If you initialize all 3 models everytime an instance of abstract gets created and themself are all extending abstract ... Hope you get what I mean. A better way would be to pass an instance of a specific class to methods which needs them to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem is that you are nesting your classes like russian dolls. You shouldn't have your Abstract class both *contain* model/view/helper, and be the *parent* of model/view/helper.

I'd caution against using extension just to ensure a class is in-scope.

Generally you can think of it this way: use **extension** when your class has shared behaviors or properties as it's parent, *but* it either needs additional functionality, or modifications to existing functionality.

The "abstract" class you defined shares no attributes or methods between Model/View/Helper, so Model/View/Helper should not probably extend from it.

If however you want a "container" class that contains instances of each of these class types, just make it a standalone class, don't extend it, for example:

```
class Container{
    public $model;
    public $view;
    public $helper;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->model = new model();
        $this->view = new view();
        $this->helper = new helper();
    }

    public function showAction(){
        if($this->helper->getParam('browse')){
            //something
        }else{
            $profiles= $this->model->getProfiles();
        }
        echo $this->view->toHtml($profiles);
}
```

Then instantiate it only once at the start someplace:

```
$action = isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : 'show';
$class = new Container();
```

Then, if you want to call something from Model inside Helper, this can be done a number of ways.

One option, pass a reference to this class and keep it inside Helper:

```
// Inside Container
public function __construct(){
    $this->model = new model();
    $this->view = new view();
    $this->helper = new helper($model);
}
```

The Helper class would look like:

```
class Helper{
    protected $model; 

    public function __construct($model){
        $this->model = $model;  
    }

    public function someHelperMethod(){
        if($this->model->someAnotherMethod()){
           //some code
           }
            //some code
        return $profiles;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tnx, this makes sense. The only missing thing is what if I need to pass also reference of helper class to model. I guess I would need to pass it to method (if the method require helper) when calling it.

Comment: That could work too, passing it along with the method that needs it. But just to expand, you can also send a copy of helper back to model too -- just add a `setHelper($helper)` function to Model, and call it in the same constructor after instantiating the helper. Generally though I'd spend some time looking at some common Design Patterns someplace, particularly MVC ones, as all of the examples I said could be ill advised depending on specific use case :/